# Unable to shutdown mongodb server - unexpected error: "shutdownServer failed: unauthorized" at src/mongo/shell/assert.js:7

Tags: mongodb, shutdown

I am trying to shutdown one of the mongodb instance in a 3 node replica set. The config file has auth set to 1. I have a admin account that has userAdminAnyDatabase role and I logged to admin database with that account. However when I run db.shutdownServer() I get the following error

> db.shutdownServer()
>   assert failed : unexpected error: "shutdownServer failed: unauthorized"
>   Error: Printing Stack Trace
>       at printStackTrace (src/mongo/shell/utils.js:37:15)
>       at doassert (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:6:5)
>       at assert (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:14:5)
>       at DB.shutdownServer (src/mongo/shell/db.js:346:9)
>       at (shell):1:4
>   Mon Jun 23 12:52:51.839 assert failed : unexpected error: "shutdownServer failed: unauthorized" at src/mongo/shell/assert.js:7

I created another user that has both dbAdminAnyDatabase and userAdminAnyDatabase roles and that also gets the same error.

Can someone help me with this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If running MongoDB 2.4 a user with the **clusterAdmin** role is needed to run db.shutdownServer(). A full list of user roles for MongoDB 2.4 is available here: http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/user-privileges/

If on MongoDB 2.6 you would use the **hostManager** role instead. See the following page for 2.6 roles: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/